# Skin condition causing red spots and light hair loss

Tags: cats, skin-condition, fleas

My 14 year old American Short Hair has three spots on her ears and now one on her forehead where there is light hair loss, and in the centre is a small red dot like blood congealed over an insect bite or sting.

I took her to the vet's last month, and even though one spot still had the dot remaining he said it was nothing in particular and just wait for the hair to grow back. Since then two more spots have appeared, so what might be the cause?

She's an indoor cat, but hadn't recently been treated for fleas etc.

(I've since used Broadline, but that caused a 5 cm diameter bald patch at the application point!)

Comment: If this is caused by insects or parasites (which I don't know), you should treat the pillows, blankets and bedding of your cat as well as the cat itself. But all the bedding into a sealed plastic bag and throw it into the freezer for 2 weeks. That usually kills any insects including their eggs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My cat was adopted at four and when we introduced her to a kitten a few months later, she became very stressed. She didn’t have the blood marks but she did have several scabs across her body. All in places that you wouldn’t think her paws or mouth could reach. (Back of the neck, certain part of belly, head, and mid to base of spine). There were probably 4-5 total. She had fleas before but none of my cats go outside and the kitten was flea free. So we ruled out fleas. She didn’t seem to notice the little scabs but I could feel them. We didn’t notice any hair loss to a major level but perhaps a little. We just continued to monitor her and they eventually all went away. We brushed her everyday and made sure she was getting a good diet and water. I think they were stress induced some how. I’m no vet, or student of feline science, but I do know that cats are over sensitive to everything. My girl was a long hair cat as well, which makes her even more sensitive. Look to see if there’s anything that has stressed her out. Does she itch at them? Bite at them? If this is the case it might be some kind of bug or insect. If they don’t go away, or if you notice another pop up, I would bring back to the vet. Perhaps another vet too, to get cross information.